# Should we have a tag specifically for Friday Night Magic?

Tags: discussion, tags

Recently, we had a question [How can I find a FNM-competitive affordable deck?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/32928/3389) that was tagged with [friday-night-magic](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/friday-night-magic). I'm not a Magic player, but I was a little confused by this because it was my understanding that this was just a casual event that stores ran, rather than a specific set of rules (i.e. it's not like [mtg-commander](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-commander), or the RPG event *Dungeons & Dragons Adventures*). I figured that we could just retag this with [tournament](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tournament), which already is on a number of Magic questions.

There was some disagreement about this in the chat, so I'm bringing this up on meta. Should we have a tag specifically for Friday Night Magic?

Answer (score 7):

Friday Night Magic (FNM) is just an event on Fridays (whodathunk?) that local game stores hold for playing magic. Generally they are a recognized format like Standard, Modern or Commander, and if the store is recognized by Wizards they offer some prize support (promos).  Each store can do FNM how they want, but it ends up being similar between the stores.  As it's a (mostly) casual event (and we don't even have categories for GPs or PTs), I don't think a tag is needed for it.  If anything, since FNMs tend to be at the regular Rules Enforcement Level, that would be a more likely tag, and that is still a bit unnecessary.

Comment: I agree, I don't think we need a tag more specific that [tag:tournament], but if we did want one [tag:regular-rel] would be better than [tag:friday-night-magic].